# minikube dashboard stuck on verifying proxy health

Tags: kubernetes, installation, loading, minikube

I'm pretty new to kubernetes and minikube.

I'm just following the installation tutorial of minikube.

I tried to run the `minikube dashboard`command but this is what it's doing :

```
  Verifying the dashboard health
  Starting proxy...
  Verifying the proxy health
```

and nothing more happen during one hour ...

What I already tried :

```
stop minikube
delete current config,
start minikube
minikube dashboard
```

I get the exact same behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got fixed by himself after one hour ...

I tried to restart the dashboard command without restarting minikube and it works ...

Answer (score 1):

login to minikube vm

```
minikube ssh
```

and try pinging google.com from minikube vm

```
ping google.com
```

if you get error, edit the resolv.conf file (inside minikube vm)

```
sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf
```

change the name server ip to 8.8.8.8

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8 ( inside minikube ssh vm )
```

use exit to get out of minikube vm, delete all dashboards pods and rerun dashboard command

```
 minikube dashboard
```

this has worked for me.